# Twist of 2-Selmer group can be arbitrary large

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $Sel^2(E/\Bbb{Q})$ be a 2-Selmer group of an elliptic curve $E/\Bbb{Q}$.
For $D\in \Bbb{Z}$, let $E_D/\Bbb{Q}$ denote its quadratic twist by $D$.

It is known that

> $Sel^2(E_D/\Bbb{Q})$ can be arbitrary large for fixed $E/\Bbb{Q}$ when we vary $D$.

I heard this is straight forward when $E(\Bbb{Q})[2]\neq 0$, it is straightforward.

But I couldn't come up with how to enlarge $Sel^2$ even in the case   $E(\Bbb{Q})[2]\neq 0$.

Could you give me a hint or outline or sketch of this fact ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if this classes as straightforward, but one way to prove it is to use duality. Since $E(\mathbb Q)[2]\ne 0$, $E$ admits a cyclic $2$-isogeny $\phi\colon E\to E'$, and to prove that $\mathrm{Sel}_2$ can be arbitrarily large, it is sufficient to prove that $\mathrm{Sel}_\phi$ can be. But duality tells you that $\mathrm{Sel}_\phi/\mathrm{Sel}_{\hat\phi}$ is more or less the ratio of the Tamagawa numbers of $E_D$ and $E_D'$, which can be made arbitrarily large by adding more and more prime factors to $D$ that satisfy easy-to-check conditions depending on $E$.

Comment: I can add more detail if this is the type of thing you had in mind. It may be that there is a much simpler method though!

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, that's what I wanted to know. I want to know  more detail.

Comment: @Mathmo$123$.  I may have seen the same kind of argument in Kloosterman's paper. Thought it involved multiplying many prime numbers and then twisting them, but now I understand it's about multiplying prime numbers that satisfy conditions related to the Tamagawa number. I am particularly curious about what specific conditions these primes should meet.

Comment: @Mathmo123  Could you tell what is the conditions on primes factors of $D$ exactly ?

Comment: The conditions depend on the elliptic curve $E$, in particular, local conditions at the prime $p$, such as the dimension of $E(\mathbb Q_p)[2]$. A good reference is chapter $3$ of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.7030.pdf), but I think this flavour of argument first appears in *D.R. Heath-Brown. The size of Selmer groups for the congruent number problem, II. Inventiones
mathematicae, 118(1):331–370, 1994*.